# Why are Redux actions called actions if they don't actually perform any action (I.E. dispatch)

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-actions

## Why are Redux actions called actions if they don't actually act upon the data and instead just return a payload?

Is there any other use for an action other than to be dispatched, why don't actions dispatch when called?

Is this just a way to future proof an app for use with multiple stores?

This also creates a need for mapDispatchToProps which is usually completely boilerplate code to wrap actions with dispatch calls

It can often be summarized with this function that takes an object of actions
and returns a mapDispatchToProps function

```
// mapActionsToDispatchProps.js
const mapActionsToDispatchProps = actions => {
  return dispatch => (
    actions.mapEntries(action => (
      (...args) => dispatch(action(...args))
    )
  )
)
export default mapActionsToDispatchProps
```

[Object.mapEntries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57402628/3458162) example.

#### Edit

I see that last question about mapDispachToProps being mostly boilerplate can be avoided by passing an object of actions directly and connect will map them for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that an *action* is just a plain object with a `type` field, while an *action creator* is a function that returns an action object.

The naming here is because Redux is originally an implementation of the ["Flux Architecture"](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview), and [Flux defines "actions" as "simple objects with a `type` field"](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview#structure-and-data-flow).  The question of whether to name them "actions" or "events" was heavily debated, and the conclusion was to keep using the Flux terminology since that's what existing Flux users would be most familiar with.

Now, of course, no one remembers that other Flux libraries existed, and many people assume that the term "action" was invented by the Redux team at some point.

For historical details, see the discussions in the following Redux issues:

- [#140: Docs improvements](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/140)
- [#195: Breaking API Changes for 1.0](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/195#issuecomment-119199129)
- [#384: Recommend that action constants be named in past tense](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/384)
- [#891: Is Redux conflating actions with events?](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/891)

And yes, we *strongly* encourage that folks use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object).